# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse pattern for log back

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j

I am getting this error in my application which is running on EMR
Here  are few details about this error

1. It is not consistent. This error comes once in while (in two days or in a week also).
2. We have tried building JARs from Local /Jenkins/Maven but no luck. Still this errors appears.
3. Verified class in the JAR file and it is present at correct location.
4. It does not look like corrupted jars or class not present issue as this error is not consistent.

Here is the complete stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse pattern '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$SerializerBuilder.build(PatternLayout.java:490)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:61)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build(PatternLayout.java:770)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.setToDefault(AbstractConfiguration.java:715)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at com.company.search.tcp.rdf.jumper.driver.processclass.processMessages(processclass.java:110)
    at com.company.search.ecp.tcp.jumper.driver.processclass.lambda$process$5dfe0a07$1(processclass.java:95)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:690)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$200(ZipFile.java:61)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasNext(ZipFile.java:512)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(ZipFile.java:507)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasNext(JarFile.java:264)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(JarFile.java:273)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInJar(ResolverUtil.java:347)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.findInPackage(ResolverUtil.java:233)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromPackage(PluginRegistry.java:225)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:132)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(PatternLayout.java:255)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$SerializerBuilder.build(PatternLayout.java:473)
    ... 29 more
```

we don't use the pattern mentioned in the error stack trace at all .
We use below in our code

```
name="OFF_File_appender"
fileName="$${sys:spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/log4j2.log"
filePattern="$$${sys:spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/log4j2.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}"
>
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5level %c{3}[%X{currentContext}] - [log4j2] %msg%n"/>
```

Comment: The error seems clear to me. You are trying to log a message, using Log4j, from the code of method `processMessages`, in class `processclass` and the pattern you are using is invalid. I suggest that you check the syntax for patterns in Log4j.

Comment: @Abra the issue we don't use this pattern at all .I have updated the question with the pattern that we uses